# ease-in-out becomes instant at first run?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code, which isn't easing the images in or out, but is showing them instant?

But it does not seem to do that? -  it shows up instantly ?

Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<style>
.features-read-mode {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 21s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>

 <script>
 $('.js-feature').each(function()) {
    var self = $(this);
    var startPosition;
    var totalFeatures = self.children().length;
    var maxHeightBuffer = 500;

     function getMaxHeight() {
     var maxHeight = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < totalFeatures; i++)
     {
         maxHeight += self.children().eq(i),height();
     }
     maxHeight += maxHeightBuffer;
     return maxHeight;
    }

    function expand() {
        setTimeOut(function() {
            self.css('max-height', getMaxHeight() + 'px');
        }, 1);
    }

    function collapse(startPos) {
        self.css('max-height', startPos + 'px');
    }

      self.find('.js-button-expand-collapse').on('click', function() {
      collapse(startPosition);

    } else {
      startPosition = self.height();
      self.addClass('features-read-more--expanded');
      expand();
    }
  });
 }
    </script>
</html>
```

The function calls expand which then updates the maxHeight value which the transition should ease-in-out to.  This only works after is has been executed once.  The first executing doesn't ease-in-out, but goes to max-height instant? how come?

Comment: 1) The style of your `.features-read-mode` misses its closing `}`. 2) Your script misses its closing `</script>`.

Comment: Fixed the missing